# Visual Studio 2005 Error: Subreport could not be shown

Tags: asp.net, .net, report, rdlc, subreport

I got a table in my rdlc report. I inserted a subreport to this table's cell. If I put a textbox in my subreport it is working, but after I put a table to my subreport I get: Error: Subreport could not be shown. The table doesn't contain anything just constant data.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please, supply some code in your question that would show how you bind data to your subreport.

Comment: The problem was that i didn't bind the data to my subreport :) thank you, now its working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didn't bind the data to my subreport :) thank you, now its working properly :)